# How exactly do you cast the Infinite Tsukuyomi?

Tags: naruto

Obito tried to cast it using the Divine Tree's bud and Ten Tail's power.

Madara did it by absorbing the Divine Tree and using the Rinne Sharingan.

Kaguya did it just by eating the Divine Tree's chakra fruit (which I believe only contains a fraction of Ten Tail's/Divine Tree's power).

So what is the working behind casting the Infinite Tsukuyomi?

Comment: Remember the 1 question per post policy. You can post your side question as a new post.

Comment: Ok sorry ..... :)

Comment: A few days ago, I answered a similar question if you read the links that let you find answers to those questions. I think you should look for more ...

Comment: lol, what a coincidence, that question was mine too but here I am asking how the 3 of them can launch the infinite tsukuyomi using different methods?

Comment: Well, scientists have been trying to investigate that for a long time now. Mr.Jones of Crapland University recently published a journal in which he describes how was unsuccessful in casting the infinite tsukuyomi. Please go through it.

Answer (score 1):

Infinite Tsukoyomi in simplest terms is a Genjutsu cast by reflecting the Sharingan from the surface of moon such that anyone who looks at the moon falls under the spell.

Tobi explains to the five Kage about this jutsu. That he needs his current power to increase significantly so that his Sharingan can become capable of such a feat. Thus the jutsu Inifnite Tsukoyomi doesn't depend on the way the required level of power is achieved, just that the user has that much power.

Hence Obito, Madara and Kaguya believe that they can cast it using different methods to increase their chakra.

Comment: *claps* Migoto desu.